# Why does bitcoin-cli not know about working directory of bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I have a `/ect/systemd/system/bitcoin.service` with the following content and I am wondering, why `bitcoin-cli getinfo` tells me about a configuration file elsewhere:

```
error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/pi/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)
```

Content of `bitcoin.service`, especially `-conf=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bitcoin daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -conf=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -pid=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid
# Creates /run/bitcoind owned by bitcoin
RuntimeDirectory=bitcoind
User=bitcoin
Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid
Restart=on-failure
# Hardening measures
####################
# Provide a private /tmp and /var/tmp.
PrivateTmp=true
# Mount /usr, /boot/ and /etc read-only for the process.
ProtectSystem=full
# Disallow the process and all of its children to gain
# new privileges through execve().
NoNewPrivileges=true
# Use a new /dev namespace only populated with API pseudo devices
# such as /dev/null, /dev/zero and /dev/random.
PrivateDevices=true
# Deny the creation of writable and executable memory mappings.
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: bacause it not have the information for the rpc framework, this is an comple example of bitcoin.con, [click me](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf)

Comment: Thanks, I now understood that bitcoin-cli is a client to bitcoind and bitcoind has to run in server-mode which has to be specified in the config file along with username and password, right?

Comment: yes, correct, I have answered inside this post with more [details](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90044/what-role-has-bitcoin-init-as-a-process/90048?noredirect=1#comment103113_90048)

Comment: I posted both questions but I don't think they are related. The other question is mainly about `bitcoin-init`.

Comment: yes, but include this question.

Comment: Assuming your ACLs are in check, you can always use the `includeconf` in your `/home/pi/` config to point to your config file in `/home/bitcoin`.  Then just name the `datadir` option in the `/home/bitcoin` config.  This should allow you to use the `authcookie` without messing with user/pass.  Not that it's cleaner or easier, its just what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitcoin-cli` has to be run with the same `user` as `bitcoind`.

Otherwise it will check for the configuration file in the wrong directory, because the **default directory** is the `home` directory of the user the process is run by.

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin-cli use the bitcoin-rpc, so for used a bitcoin-cli, you must ran the bitcoind with the configuration and when it is OK, you can get command with the bitcoin-cli

A simple file configuration could be it

```
##
## bitcoin.conf configuration file. Lines beginning with # are comments.
##
# On client-side, you add the normal user/password pair to send commands:
rpcuser=alice
rpcpassword=bob
```

or you can run the `bitcoind with this command bitcoind -rpcuser=alice -rpcpassword=bob`